# How to properly show an error message inside a fieldset

Tags: html, accessibility, markup, semantic-markup

I want to have a `fieldset`-tag to show an error message.

When doing something like:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Some Legend</legend>
  <div role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="all">
    My Error Message
  </div>

  ...
  <!-- formfields -->
</fieldset>
```

The screen reader isn't reading the error message, but when wrapping the error message inside the `<label>`-tag it is reading it but it feels wrong.

What would be the proper way to show an error message inside a `fieldset`-tag in terms of accessibility?

Answer (score 1):

`aria-live` regions work pretty well if you follow a few simple rules.

- the element with `aria-live` must exist at page load time.  that is, you can't dynamically add that attribute after the page is loaded.
- if using the default [`aria-relevant`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-relevant) value (that is, if you don't specify `aria-relevant`), then changes are only announced if you change the text in the region or if you add child DOM nodes.  In your case, you have "all" so child DOM nodes that are removed will also be announced.  Note that hiding or unhiding elements is not considered a change in the DOM so will not be announced.

A few side notes:

- in general, `aria-live="polite"` is sufficient for the majority of cases.  `aria-live="assertive"` is rarely needed except for extremely urgent messages.
- using `role="alert"` gives you an implicit `aria-live="assertive"`.  you don't have to specify `aria-live`.

Comment: Great info. To be a little more explicit, the text inside a `role=alert` tag is not read on page load, only once it has been updated.

Comment: That's correct, and I didn't say it would be read on page load.  I said the attributes/roles must be set by page load time because some browser/AT combinations do not allow them to be set after page load.  I was also assuming the general concept of `aria-live` was understood - that the element is not read until it changes.

Comment: I'm curious what the solution is for single page app (SPA) which produce dynamic html on load

Comment: @grazerbeam would need more details. Are you talking about announcing new content in an SPA or are you still talking about error messages in an SPA?  The latter works fine. Add new content that has aria-live and when an error is generated inside the live region, it’ll be announced.

Comment: Well a SPA html file might just be a single div and then builds out all the html when the page finishes loading assets. 

In this case any new Dom element with aria-live is not following the above first rule of existing on load time.

Comment: That’s ok. The above “rule” is a general guidance. You can add `aria-live` regions dynamically but they won’t announce any changes if text is added at the same time the live element is added. But if you add the live element then the user causes an error, that error will be announced.